# Count subsets of array which qualify min(subset)+max(subset) < k

Tags: algorithm

Was asked this question in an interview, didn't have a better answer than generating all possible subsets.
Example:

```
a = [4,2,5,7] k = 8

output = 4

[2],[4,2],[2,5],[4,2,5]
```

Interviewer tried implying sorting the array should help, but I still couldn't figure out a better-than-brute-force solution. Will appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sort the array
2. For an element `x` at index `l`, do a binary search on the array to get index of the maximum integer in the array which is `< k-x`. Let the index be `r`.
3. For all subsets where `min(subset) = x`, we can have any element with index in range `(l,r]`. Number of subsets with `min(subset) = x` becomes the total number of possible subsets for `(r-l)` elements, so count = `2^(r-l)` (or `0` if `r<l`).
   (Note: in all such subsets, we are fixing `x`. That's why the range `(l,r]` isn't inclusive of `l`)
4. You have to iterate over the array, use the above process for each element/index to get the count of subsets where our current element is the minimum and the subset satisfies the given constraint. If you find an element with `count=0`, break the iteration.

This should work with a `0(N*log(N))` complexity, good enough for an interview question imo.

For the given example, sorted array = `[2,4,5,7]`.

1. For element `2`, `l=0` and `r=2`. Count = `2^(2-0) = 4` (covers `[2],[4,2],[2,5],[4,2,5]`
2. For element `4`, `l=1` and `r=0`. Count = `0`, and we break the iteration.

Comment: after the first iteration of counting the subsets between a[0] and a[r], why not continue search from r+1? searching from first + 1 will introduce duplicates?

Comment: @susdu we are fixing the minimum element in each iteration. Edited the answer as well

Comment: a = [1,2,3,4] k=4, left=0 right=2. in this range we cannot have any element in range (l,r], because [2,3] does not qualify for k=4

Comment: @susdu if `left=0`, then `1` will be a part of all generated subsets. So `[1,2]` would be valid. (`right = 1` and not `2`)

Comment: for first iteration and k=4, left=0 and max index returned from search is 2, in this case range is [1,3] but cannot count all positions in this range because [2,3] is not valid

Comment: @susdu have you read the answer? If you have `left=0`, how will you generate a subset that DOESN'T have `1` in it?

Comment: I understand now , missed the not-inclusive-of-left part

Comment: No way this can be done better than O(2^n) since you need to list all subsets in the worst case.

Comment: @yzhang where are the subsets being "listed"? Only the count is being computed

Comment: @AbhinavMathur My bad. I thought the OP needed to generate all subsets.

Answer (score 4):

The interviewer implied that sorting the array would help and it does help. I'll try to explain.

Taking the array and `k` values you stated:

```
a = [4,2,5,7]
k = 8
```

Sorting the array will yield:

```
a_sort = [2,4,5,7]
```

Now we can consider the following procedure:

1. set ii = 0, jj = 1
2. choose `a_sort[ii]` as a part of your subset

   2.1. If `2 * a_sort[ii] >= k`, you are done. else, the subset `[a_sort[ii]]` holds the condition and is a part of the solution.
3. add `a_sort[ii+jj]` to your subset

   3.1. If `a_sort[ii] + a_sort[ii+jj] < k`,

   3.1.1. the subset `[a_sort[ii], a_sort[ii+jj]]` holds the condition and is a part of the solution, as well as any subset which consists of any additional number of elements `a_sort[kk]` where `ii< kk < ii+jj`

   3.1.2. set `jj += 1` and go back to step 3.

   3.2. else, `set ii += 1`, `jj = ii + 1`, go back to step 2

With your input this procedure should return:

```
[[2], [2,4],[2,5],[2,4,5]]
# [2,7] results in 9 > 8 and therefore you move to [4]
# Note that for [4] subset you get 8 = 8 which is not smaller than 8, we are done
```

### Explenation

- if you have a subset of [a_sort[ii]] which does not hold `2 * a_sort[ii] < k`, adding additional numbers to the subset will only yield `min(subset)+max(subset) > 2 * a_sort[ii] > k and therefore there will not be any additional subsets which hold the wanted condition. Moreover, by setting a subset of [a_sort[ii+1]] will results in` 2 * a_sort[ii+1] >= 2 * a_sort[ii] > k` sinse a_sort is sorted. Therefore you will not find any additional subsets.
- for jj > ii, if `a_sort[ii] + a_sort[ii+jj] < k` then you can push any number if members from `a_sort` into the subset, as long as the index `kk` will be bigger than `ii` and lower than `ii+jj` since `a_sort` is sorted, and adding these members to the subset will not change the value of `min(subset)+max(subset)` which will remain `a_sort[ii] + a_sort[ii+jj]` and we already know that this value is smaller thank `k`

### Getting the count

In case you simply want to the possible subsets, this can be done easier than generating the subsets themselves.

Assuming  that for `ii > jj` the condition holds, i.e.  `a_sort[ii] + a_sort[ii+jj] < k`. If `jj = ii + 1` there is an addition of 1 possible subset. If `jj > ii + 1` there are `jj - ii - 1` additional elements which can be either present not not without a change of the value `a_sort[ii] + a_sort[ii+jj]`. Therefore there are a total of `2**(jj-ii-1)` additional subsets available to add to the solution group (`jj-ii-1` elements, each is independently present or not). This also holds for `jj = ii + 1` since in this case `2**(jj-ii-1) = 2**0 = 1`

Looking at the example above:

- [2] adds 1 count
- [2,4] adds 1 count (`1 = 0 + 1`)
- [2,5] adds 2 counts (`2 = 0 + 2` --> `2 **(2 - 0 - 1) = 2**1 = 2`)

A total count of 4